# How to retrieve the bucket boundaries when using mongo's $bucket aggregation?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection of 200,000+ records which include a float field `amountAwarded` (eg. 12345.67, 2342, 22 etc). I'm using MongoDB to aggregate these into buckets based on the following boundaries:

```
amountAwarded: [
        {
            $bucket: {
                groupBy: '$amountAwarded',
                boundaries: [0, 10000, 50000, 100000, 1000000, Infinity],
                output: {
                    count: { $sum: 1 }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
```

This works as expected and I get this output:

```
{
  "amountAwarded": [
    {
      _id: 0,
      count: 269
    },
    {
      _id: 10000,
      count: 67
    },
    // etc
  ]
}
```

What I really want is to reference the bucket boundaries in the output, eg:

```
{
  "amountAwarded": [
    {
      _id: 0,
      count: 269,
      lowerBound: 0,
      upperBound: 9999
    }
  ]
}
```

This means I can construct a list on the frontend showing the buckets (eg. `£0 - £9999`).

The closest I've come is adding `$min: "$amountAwarded"` (and an equivalent `$max`) to the `output`, which gives me the upper/lower values for that field in the bucketed records. This isn't right though as the numbers are obviously from the data (eg. `8762`) rather than the bucket bounds.

Is it possible to refer to the matched bucket boundaries inside the aggregation pipeline, or will I have to construct this manually after the facet is complete?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You define your boundaries yourself, so you can just [addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) on the next stage using combination of [indexOfArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfArray/) and [arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/).

Something like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
    $bucket: {
        groupBy: '$amountAwarded',
        boundaries: [0, 10000, 50000, 100000, 1000000, Infinity],
        output: {
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    }
},
{ $addFields: {
      lowerBound: "$_id",
      upperBound: { $arrayElemAt: [ 
          [0, 10000, 50000, 100000, 1000000, Infinity], 
          { $add: [
              { $indexOfArray: [
                  [0, 10000, 50000, 100000, 1000000, Infinity], "$_id"
              ] }, 
              1
          ] }
      ] }
} }
])
```

Comment: Fantastic – it didn't occur to me to just `addFields`. This works as I expected – thank you.

Comment: What if one of the buckets is empty? That bucket will be skipped in the bucket pipeline & it won't match the original list of buckets.

Comment: @ArjavDave Thanks for the comment! I really like critical thinking instead of blind copy-pasting. The $indexOfArray operator search the bucket's $_id in the last array to find the index of the element in the previous array of boundaries, so that $arrayElementAt picked the correct value. I am happy to review the answer if you can prove it wrong tho.